# optimize mysql query: medal standings

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 2 tables:

1. olympic_medalists with columns gold_country, silver_country, bronze_country
2. flags with country column

I want to list the olympic medal table accordingly. I have this query, it works, but it seems to kill mysql. Hope someone can help me with an optimized query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country AS sc,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(silver_country) 
            FROM olympic_medalists 
        WHERE silver_country = sc AND silver_country != '' 
        GROUP BY silver_country),0) AS silver_medals, 
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(gold_country) 
            FROM olympic_medalists 
        WHERE gold_country = sc AND gold_country != '' 
        GROUP BY gold_country),0) AS gold_medals,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(bronze_country) 
            FROM olympic_medalists 
        WHERE bronze_country = sc AND bronze_country != '' 
        GROUP BY bronze_country),0) AS bronze_medals
FROM olympic_medalists, flags 
GROUP BY country, gold_medals, silver_country, bronze_medals HAVING (
    silver_medals >= 1 || gold_medals >= 1 || bronze_medals >= 1)
ORDER BY gold_medals DESC, silver_medals DESC, bronze_medals DESC,   
SUM(gold_medals+silver_medals+bronze_medals)
```

result will be like:

```
country  |  g  |  s  |  b  |  tot
---------------------------------
country1 |  9  |  5  |  2  |  16
country2 |  5  |  5  |  5  |  15
```

and so on

Thanks!

```
olympic medalists:

  `id` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `gold_country` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `silver_country` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `bronze_country` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)

flags

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `country` varchar(128) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

Comment: could you post your schema? I am also not quite sure what you mean by killing mysql?

Comment: 'killing mysql' - when i ran this, it takes a while for the page to load, and that's on a local server. when I ran it on a live server, basically takes forever to load and mysql dies. i'll add the schema to the post

Comment: sorry to ask this, but would it be possible to modify your schema? I am assuming the varchar in flags is country or country code, and this is repeated in Olympic medalists for the meddling categories? IT might be slightly cleaner to update/insert records if this is not repeated. Maybe change flag to country and make join tables for gold, silver and bronze and put specific information there like country id, event, athelete name etc (sorry to suggest changing your schema and I know its not always possible) it will make things simpler in the long run though. These indexes will help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be much more efficient than your current solution of executing three different `SELECT` subqueries for each row in a cross-joined relation (and you wonder why it stalls out!):

```
SELECT    a.country,
          COALESCE(b.cnt,0)     AS g,
          COALESCE(c.cnt,0)     AS s,
          COALESCE(d.cnt,0)     AS b,
          COALESCE(b.cnt,0) +
          COALESCE(c.cnt,0) +
          COALESCE(d.cnt,0)     AS tot
FROM      flags a
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   gold_country, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
          FROM     olympic_medalists 
          GROUP BY gold_country
          ) b ON a.country = b.gold_country
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   silver_country, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
          FROM     olympic_medalists 
          GROUP BY silver_country
          ) c ON a.country = c.silver_country
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   bronze_country, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
          FROM     olympic_medalists 
          GROUP BY bronze_country
          ) d ON a.country = d.bronze_country
```

---

What would be even faster is instead of storing the actual textual country name in each of the gold, silver, and bronze columns, just store the integer-based country `id`. Comparisons on integers are always going to be faster than comparisons on strings.

Moreover, once you replace each country name in the `olympic_medalists` table with the corresponding id's, you'll want to create an index on each column (gold, silver, and bronze).

Updating the textual names to be their corresponding `id`'s instead is a simple task and could be done with a single `UPDATE` statement in conjunction with some `ALTER TABLE` commands.

Comment: this really is fast. exactly what I was looking for. thanks! I'll try to follow your suggestions regarding storing country IDs instead of the country itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT F.COUNTRY,IFNULL(B.G,0) AS G,IFNULL(B.S,0) AS S,
IFNULL(B.B,0) AS B,IFNULL(B.G+B.S+B.B,0) AS TOTAL
FROM FLAGS F LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT A.COUNTRY,
         SUM(CASE WHEN MEDAL ='G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS G,
         SUM(CASE WHEN MEDAL ='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S,
         SUM(CASE WHEN MEDAL ='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
      FROM   
          (SELECT GOLD_COUNTRY AS COUNTRY,'G' AS MEDAL 
           FROM OLYMPIC_MEDALISTS WHERE GOLD_COUNTRY IS NOT NULL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT SILVER_COUNTRY AS COUNTRY,'S' AS MEDAL 
           FROM OLYMPIC_MEDALISTS WHERE SILVER_COUNTRY IS NOT NULL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT BRONZE_COUNTRY AS COUNTRY,'B' AS MEDAL 
           FROM OLYMPIC_MEDALISTS WHERE BRONZE_COUNTRY IS NOT NULL)A
      GROUP BY A.COUNTRY)B
 ON F.COUNTRY=B.COUNTRY
 ORDER BY IFNULL(B.G,0) DESC,IFNULL(B.S,0) DESC,
          IFNULL(B.B,0) DESC,IFNULL(B.G+B.S+B.B,0) DESC,F.COUNTRY
```